# jQuery How to add/remove dynamically created elements from dynamically created divs?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, selector

I am attempting to make a form that has 3 fields. It also has buttons to add another set of fields called modules. This part works. Each module that is created, should then be able to create more sets of fields below them called tasks.

The hierarchy goes:

```
 Project:

    Module:
      Task 1:
      Task 2:

    Module 2:
      Task 3:
      Task 4:
```

The problem I'm having is when I add tasks. You can add modules, and they correctly push down the original form buttons. When I try to add tasks to a div that lies within the module div, both dynamically created, it adds the tasks to the wrong place and they just run through the content below them. The fiddle below is the current state I'm in:

http://jsfiddle.net/smkarber/ezdk96z3/16/

Comment: When I click on 'Add task' - nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, try now. I think I linked the wrong update before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the jQuery used on this fiddle iteration:

http://jsfiddle.net/smkarber/ezdk96z3/19/

Basically, I had to navigate using familial relationships, and since the hierarchy will always be the same, it is perfectly reliable.

```
$('#div_form').on('click', '.f_addTask', function() {

    $(this).parent().parent().children('.div_task').append('<div class="p_task">
    <label for="t_name">Task Name: </label><input type="textbox" class="t_name p_fields" 
    /><br/><label for="t_desc">Description: </label><input type="textbox" class="t_desc 
    p_fields" /><br/><label 
    for="t_date">Due Date: </label><input type="date" class="t_date p_fields" /><br/>
    </div>');

});

$('#div_form').on('click', '.f_undoAddTask', function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().children('.div_task').children('.p_task:last')
        .remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global counter, and append this counter to the container where you want to insert the tasks:

```
'<div class="div_task_'+count+'"></div>'
'<input type="button" value="Add Task" id="f_addTask" onclick="addTask('+count+')" />'
'<input type="button" value="Undo Add" id="f_undoAddTask" onclick="removeTask('+count+')" />'
```

and then on the JS

```
function addTask(counter){
    $('#div_task_'+counter).append('')
};
```

Comment: Does this work on dynamically created elements? I keep having problems with binding on elements that didn't exist when the document was created.

Comment: this is another issue, see this link for more details : http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2013/06/javascript-jQuery-click-not-working-for-dynamically-created-items.html

Comment: I couldn't get it to work this way, but it is probably a failing on my part. I did manage however to solve my issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was working on typing up my solution. Thanks, again.